# Visual Studio 2022 se cierra al elegir elementos de la barra de herramientas

Tags: visual-studio, framework

He instalado Visual Studio 2022 y cuando trato de elegir elementos de la caja de herramientas, me da un error y cierra la visualización.
Se abre la ventana y cuando lleva unos segundos se cierra el visual por completo

Los errores que me muestra en el visor de eventos son:

1.Aplicación: devenv.exe Versión del marco: v4.0.30319 Descripción: El proceso finalizó debido a un error interno en el tiempo de ejecución de .NET en la dirección IP 00007FFA2C39BC04 (00007FFA2BF80000) con el código de salida 80131506.

2. Nombre de la aplicación con errores: devenv.exe, versión: 17.6.33829.357, marca de tiempo: 0x649e1133 Nombre del módulo con errores: clr.dll, versión: 4.8.9167.0, marca de tiempo: 0x648f6bcc Código de excepción: 0xc0000005 Compensación de error: 0x000000000041bc0 4 Identificador de proceso defectuoso: 0x2178 Hora de inicio de la aplicación con errores: 0x01d9b5609da2915b Ruta de la aplicación con errores: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe Ruta del módulo con errores: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ clr.dll Identificador de informe: 6f8cce26-0af0-4979-97b1-aacab821d821 Nombre completo del paquete con errores: Identificador de aplicación relativo del paquete defectuoso:

He intentado reparar Visual Studio, también lo he desinstalado y vuelto a instalar pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Esto te pasa en cualquier proyecto, por ejemplo en uno nuevo?

Comment: Si me pasa, con cualquier proyecto nuevo o existente.
Incluso sin ningún proyecto